# Why does in my case context creates the bean?

Tags: java, spring, spring-annotations

Could you tell me why does in my case context creates the `"simple"` bean if it has circular dependencies? To my mind, an exception that says about circular dependencies must be thrown!
Configuration class:

```
package config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "service")
public class AppConfig {
}
```

Simple class:

```
package service;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class Simple {

    @Autowired
    private Simple simple;


    public Simple getSimple() {
        return simple;
    }
}
```

And the launcher:

```
import config.AppConfig;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext;
import service.Simple;


public class Launcher {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(AppConfig.class);
        Simple simple1 = ctx.getBean("simple", Simple.class);
        System.out.println(simple1.getSimple());
    }

}
```

The output of the app is "service.Simple@6b53e23f". If I add the constructor

```
@Autowired
public Simple(Simple simple) {
    this.simple = simple;
}
```

then an exception `"Error creating bean with name 'simple': Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference?"` occurs.

So why is the bean created when I put `@Autowired` n the field?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because setting of the `simple` field is only done *after* creating the `Simple` instance and at that point you have a valid `Simple` instance to assign to the field. That is field injection. You do not need an instances of the the autowired fields when creating the instance of your `Simple` class.

Using constructor injection on the other hand you need valid instances for all the constructor parameters. So you need a `Simple` instance to create an instance of `Simple` which of course does not work.

Comment: Do you mean that field injection equals set property injection? BTW, anyway it seems that StackOverFlow exception must be thrown, mustn’t it?

Comment: @Pavel "field injection equals set property injection", no, but they are similar, e.g. they both happen after the constructor finished. No, a StackOverflow does not have to happen, that depends entirely on the implementation of the injection logic. You will have exactly one instance of `Simple` which has a reference to itself in the `simple` field.

Comment: Because beans are singletons?

Comment: @Pavel maybe, but imagine the (pseudo)-code being: `Object o = createBeanOfType(Simple.class); beans.register(o); o.forEachAutowiredField(field -> field.set(beans.get(field.getType())));`. You create the `Simple` instance, register it in your bean registry, then try to fill all the autowired fields which in the end will retrieve the just registered instance from the registry again.

Comment: If I put @Scope(value = ConfigurableBeanFactory.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE) on the class then "Error creating bean with name 'simple': Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference?" occurs.

Comment: @Pavel now you have wandered into spring territory that I know nothing about / cannot reason about.

Comment: Making it prototype scoped still doesn't make the rules different. You still get a single instance (the proxy) which delegates to the scoped proxy. When there is a circular reference and you try to use constructor injection that simply won't work. No matter how much proxying you throw at it. If you have class A that needs class B and vice-versa that will simply never work (when using constructor based injection).

Answer (score 0):

So, the spring when it tries to create a bean, it first tries to resolve all the Autowired (dependency injection). In our case, you are trying to inject the same class. Which means, Spring while creating Simple bean, it tries to resolve injected classes which in turn is the same class.

There is a circular dependency which throws the error.